# Writing a function/method containing conditionals in prolog

Tags: function, if-statement, prolog

I'm new to Prolog, and so I came here to know and learn about this new language from you fine people.

I'm writing a function 'decision' which has 3 parameters `I=income`, `D= dependents`, `S=savings`, and I'm trying to find out if the person should invest in savings, stocks, or both.

Here, is my code...

```
decision(I, D, S) :-
    Minincome is 9000 + 2500*D,
    Minsaving is D*3000,

    saving(S, Minsaving) :- S < Minsaving, write('You should invest your money into savings. ').
    saving(S, Minsaving) :- S >= Minsaving,
    income(I, Minincome) :- I > Minincome, write('You should try to invest in NYSE stock market. ');
    income(I, Minincome) :- I =< Minsaving, write('You should invest your money into both, saving and stock market. ').
```

What I'm trying to do is if person has saving less than Minsaving, than he should invest in savings,

else if a person has savings greater than Minsaving and income greater than Minincome, than he should invest in stock market,

else if a person has savings greater than Minsaving and income less than Minincome, than he should invest in stock market as well as savings.

I hope I was clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but you have some typos, and you must close the definition of your `decision` predicate with a period `.` before you can define new predicates. There is no nesting of predicate definition within other predicate definitions in Prolog.

Here are some cleaned up versions of your helper predicates:

```
write_saving(S, Minsaving) :-
    S < Minsaving,
    write('You should invest your money into savings. ').
write_saving(S, Minsaving) :-
    S >= Minsaving.
    
write_investment(I, Minincome) :-
    I > Minincome,
    write('You should try to invest in NYSE stock market. ').
write_investment(I, Minincome) :-
    I =< Minincome.
```

Note that every clause ends in a period `.`, not in a comma or semicolon or anything else.

And your completed `decision` predicate can call these:

```
decision(Income, Dependents, Savings) :-
    Minincome is 9000 + 2500 * Dependents,
    Minsaving is Dependents * 3000,
    write_saving(Savings, Minsaving),
    write_investment(Income, Minincome).
```

Examples:

```
?- decision(8000, 1, 2000).
You should invest your money into savings. 
true .

?- decision(17000, 1, 4000).
You should try to invest in NYSE stock market. 
true .

?- decision(17000, 1, 2000).
You should invest your money into savings. You should try to invest in NYSE stock market. 
true .
```

Note that there is no special case for printing "you should save AND you should invest in the stock market". Since both `write_saving` AND `write_ivestment` are executed, their outputs combine. If you want to treat this differently, you must write a predicate that has *both* a `Minsaving` and a `Minincome` parameter and compare accordingly.